# How to hide UIPickerView when placed in nib file

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I choose a picker view from [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker). Its working great. When app runs it shows up. However, I want this to be shown when textfield is tapped and before that I want this to be hidden. Country picker is the subclass of UIPickerView and is placed inside the nib file. Please help.

Comment: Set it hidden in interface. Assign delegate of your textfield to trigger the editing event and use property `hidden` to manage the view.

Comment: I set hidden in the interface and its not showing when view gets load, thanks. But I didn't get the next part. How would I assign delegate to my textfield to trigger the editing event and use property hidden to manage the view? Please help

Comment: @MugheesMusaddiq you would set the picker to the Textfield `textField.inputView = picker;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow next steps:

**1.** Create IBOutlet properties in your owner class (do not forget to add UITextFieldDelegate in your header file):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CountryPicker *myPickerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

**2.** Connect your IBOutlets with your PickerView, TextField in xib. and in your `viewDidLoad` method add:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Since now you should implement UITextField delegate methods. [UITextField Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
      self.myPickerView.hidden = NO;
    }
```

This method notifies the **delegate** that the specified text field just became the first responder. You can use this method to update your delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method to show overlay views that should be visible while editing.

```
    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
      self.myPickerView.hidden = YES;
    }
```

This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status. You can use this method to update your delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method to hide overlay views that should be visible only while editing.

**EDIT1:** [GitHub Sample](https://github.com/gneil90/UITextField-StackOverflowSample)

Comment: I followed your instructions but myPickerView isn't appearing. Only keyboard appears :(

Comment: I also added this `[myTextField setInputView:myPickerView];` in `viewDidLoad` and it worked, thanks :)

Comment: It should work without that line too. I added my github sample code, just for your better understanding. Check it when you have the time.